# .htaccess and HTTP header for a certain file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to serve a .crx file in this way:

```
1) The file has the content type application/x-chrome-extension
2) The file is not served with the HTTP header X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
3) The file is served with one of the following content types:
- "text/plain"
- "application/octet-stream"
- "unknown/unknown"
- "application/unknown"
```

How do I have to set my .htaccess file to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

rule 1 and 3 contradict each other. Easiest is to just rename it to `.php` and use:

```
<? 
header('Content-Type: application/x-chrome-extension'); 
?>
...original-file-contents...
```

I don't think you need the .crx extension. If for some reason you do, you could use `file.php/fake.crx` instead of just `file.php`.